# Font in Apache FOP 1.1

Tags: apache, pdf, fonts, oracle-adf, apache-fop

Can anybody help me? I my Oracle ADF project I use Apache FOP for printing data in PDF file. Application is running on CentOS. I need use Arial font for that. I want setup Arial font via auto-detect and MANIFEST.MF. My steps for this:

1. I've added folder with font to project

   ```
   C:\dev\JdevUserDir\mywork\RIM282\ViewController\libs\font\arial.ttf
   ```
2. In ViewController.jpr I've added:

   ```
   <hash>
    <value n="id" v="Font"/>
    <value n="isJDK" v="false"/>
   </hash>
   <hash>
    <list n="classPath">
     <url path="libs/font/"/>
    </list>
    <value n="deployedByDefault" v="true"/>
    <value n="description" v="Font"/>
    <value n="id" v="Font"/>
    <value n="locked" v="true"/>
   </hash>
   ```
3. In fop.xconf I've added:

   ```
   <fonts>
    <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="bold"/>      
    <auto-detect/>
   </fonts>
   ```
4. My manifest content ViewController/src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

   ```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0    
    Name: libs/font/arial.ttf
    Content-Type: application/x-font
   ```
5. Fragment from xsl file:

   ```
   <fo:block text-align="end" 
             font-size="10pt" 
             font-family="Arial">
        Страница <fo:page-number />
   </fo:block>
   ```

But, when I open pdf file, I see ##### instead cyrillic symbols. All symbols are OK on Windows, but there is issue with cyrillic on CentOS.
  I've tried to use

```
   <font-base>./libs/font</font-base>
```

in my fop.xconf file. But instead of path relative to folder which contains fop.xconf I get this path: C:/dev/JdevUserDir/system12.2.1.2.42.161008.1648/DefaultDoma‌​in/libs/font Why?

Comment: A few days ago you got an answer by Ifurlini "The font-triplet element should be inside a font element pointing to the font file, for example". Now here the font-triplet is not inside a <font> element?

Comment: I've deleted font-triplet. I need only auto-detect, but issue is the same

Comment: Do you have a specific reason why you only want auto-detect? Giving a full path in  `<font embed-url=...` and then adding the font-triplets might get you gone quicker?

Comment: There should be no dependence on the absolute path. Only auto-detect is suitable for this goal

Comment: have you tried the Font List Command Line Tool from the bottom of [https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.2/fonts.html](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.2/fonts.html) to see if it maybe finds it but under a different name?

Comment: I've tried to use <font-base>./libs/font</font-base> in my fop.xconf file. But instead of path relative to folder which contains fop.xconf I get this path: C:/dev/JdevUserDir/system12.2.1.2.42.161008.1648/DefaultDomain/libs/font    Why?

Comment: Hm, according to [fop fonts](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.2/fonts.html) I understand that `<font-base>` is supposed to be the *absolute* part of the path. Also, I understand you are using CentOS, but c:/dev... sounds like a windows path? I dont understand how that goes together.

Comment: My developer machine on Windows, but production server on CentOS.